# Test Cases failing when triggered from another repo in GitLab

Tags: jwt, gitlab, gitlab-ci, workflow, aws-ssm

My downstream project consists of the test cases for testing the heartbeat of API. For authorization, we generate jwt token. When I run my downstream project individually everything runs fine but when I trigger the pipeline using another project it fails with error `PASSMException: An error occurred (ParameterNotFound) when calling the GetParameter operation:` . The other repo also has the same permission as the downstream project. I am triggering the downstream project using keyword trigger: in .gitlab-ci file

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

After adding numerous print statements, I found out that the piece of code that gets the private key from AWS was using default environment value. I corrected that and now it's working fine.